# Free ways to automatically get notified if new papers are published on ACM or IEEE?

Tags: publishers, ieee

I'm looking for a way, tool or technology that allows me to define keywords and/or authors and/or conferences for which I want to be notified if a new paper is published on [ACM](http://www.acm.org) or [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/index.html). I couldn't yet find a way to achieve that. What are my possibilities? It shouldn't cost any money.

Comment: Offhand google scholar alerts may be able to come close to what you want. Restrict the search terms to journals you want (and keywords of course).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've had great experience with Google Scholar Alerts. To use them, go to scholar.google.com and search for any term. In the results page, you will see a link to `Create Email Alert`. Click on that and create the alert to send you notifications.

One very good use of this is to follow specific papers. For example, I have a star paper of mine that I'm currently extending and I like to keep track of who is citing this paper. So, I search for the paper on scholar. In the results page (just under the result for the paper I'm concerned with), there's a link `Cited by 'n'`. Click on that and you get results for only those papers that cite this article. Now, create an alert on this page. This way, whenever someone refers to this paper (and Google finds out about it), you get an email. Do this for all the important literature in your field and Alerts will make sure you are kept abreast of your field.

Never miss out on an important finding!

Comment: sometimes this method is slow. For example, one of my papers was cited in November, and the citation did not show up in cited-by until March.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev: Exactly, so are there any better methods to keep track of citations as soon as they are cited?

Comment: An alert on "publication:ACM" etc. is what the asker likely wants.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I found out that Microsoft Research can be really helpful for people in academia. You can subscribe to conferences, journals, institutions or even authors by the subscription at the right top for the page. For example, check [this page](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Conference/40/icse-international-conference-on-software-engineering) for ICSE.

Plus, in the [Publications](http://research.microsoft.com/c/1043) section you can sort/filter publication in various ways. [The Academic Search](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/) section gives significant information about professors and even colleges.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JeffE. I edited the answer, now it should answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org) got all you want and constantly improves using SOTA technologies. Far better than google scholar.

Comment: Flagged as spam.

Comment: hi @scaaahu why spam? My answer is correct and concise.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Semantic Scholar? If you are, please disclose it. Also, please explain why this answers the question.

Comment: Thx for explaining. :-) I'm not affiliated, thus didn't add.

Comment: Not really a spam but while your suggestion may be good, you did not elaborate why you think "Semantic Scholar" is far better than Google Scholar. I think you should add at least a sentence to describe what's the advantage of using "Semantic Scholar" in comparison to Google Scholar.

Comment: Having just had a first look at Semantic Scholar, I'm greeted with a dropdown to choose between "All fields", "computer science" and "medicine". This... does not seem terribly comprehensive!

Comment: @Flyto questioner specifically asked for ACM and IEEE (they publish almost exclusively computer science).

Comment: @EssenceBlue for ACM, that may be true (I'm not familiar). For IEEE, lolnope. I take your point that this (based on ACM, if you're right about that) could indicate the questioner is only interested in CompSci, but it's also nice to make answers general where possible.